# TreeView с CheckBox'ми android

Tags: android, checkbox, treeview

Доброго времени суток!
Понадобилось создать список-дерево, примерно, как представлено на картинке:

[image]

Дерево состоит из чек боксов, при нажатии на родителя, выставляются/убираются галочки с дочерних элементов. Так же, помимо чекбоксов у каждого элемента дерева есть свой параметр (массив байт).

Собственно, необходимо после выставления галочек (по нажатию, допустим, кнопощки) считывать состояние чекбоксов, и у выставленных брать значения (тот самый массив байт), имя, имя вкладки и записывать в другой массив/список и т.д.

Главный вопрос состоит в том, как создать такой TreeView, где состояние дочерних элементов зависит от родителя и как присвоить им, помимо всего прочего, ещё и значения.

Облазил интернеты, нашёл не очень-то подходящие примеры.

Всё, что смог из себя выдавить, представляю ниже

ExpandableListAdapter.java

```
    public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<String> listDataHeader;
    private HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listHeaderData, HashMap<String, List<String>> listChildData){
        this.context = context;
        this.listDataHeader = listHeaderData;
        this.listDataChild = listChildData;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_row, null);
        }

        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);

        txtListChild.setText(childText);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

child_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="308dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="asd"
        android:textSize="20dip" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/lblListChildCheckbox"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:textSize="17dp" />



</LinearLayout>
```

group_row.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
            android:layout_width="306dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/lblListHeaderCheckbox"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="17dp" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

listings.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:andoid="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
        andoid:layout_height="match_parent"
        andoid:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            andoid:id="@+id/add_template"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
            andoid:layout_height="wrap_content"
            andoid:layout_gravity="center"
            andoid:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            andoid:text="Добавить шаблон" />

        <ExpandableListView
            andoid:id="@+id/listing"
            andoid:layout_width="match_parent"
            andoid:layout_height="wrap_content"></ExpandableListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Непосредственно сам класс, где это дерево заполняется

Choise_list.java

```
public class Choise_List extends Activity {

    private Button add_template;

    class Lists{
        String page;
        String name;
        String type;
        byte[] val;
    }

    Context context;

    ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
    ExpandableListView expListView;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
    List<String> pages;

    ArrayList< Map<String, String> > childDataItem = new ArrayList<>();

    List<Lists> structure_list = new ArrayList<>();

    public void createListsList(ArrayList<byte[]> ch_check) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        for (int i = 0; i < ch_check.size(); i++){
            if(Arrays.equals( ch_check.get(i), "PAGE".getBytes( Charset.forName("UTF-8") ) ) ){
                Lists lists = new Lists();
                int state = i;
                lists.page = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.name = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.type = new String( ch_check.get(++state), "UTF-8" );
                lists.val = ch_check.get(++state);

                i = state;
                structure_list.add(lists);
            }
        }
    }

    private void prepareListData(){

        HashSet<String> used = new HashSet<>();

        int count = 0;

        pages = new ArrayList<>();
        listDataChild = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

        for(int i = 0; i < structure_list.size(); i++){
            if(used.contains(structure_list.get(i).page)){
                continue;
            } else {
                used.add(structure_list.get(i).page);
            }

            String new_page_name = "";
            ArrayList<Integer> positions = new ArrayList<>();

            positions.add(i);
            for(int j = i + 1; j < structure_list.size(); j++){

                if(structure_list.get(i).page.equals(structure_list.get(j).page)){
                    positions.add(j);
                }
            }

            childDataItem = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

            List<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(Integer p : positions){
                new_page_name = structure_list.get(p).page;
                child.add(structure_list.get(p).name);
            }
            pages.add(new_page_name);
            listDataChild.put(pages.get(count), child);
            count++;
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.listings);


        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.listing);

        ArrayList<byte[]> ch_check = new ArrayList<>();

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            MyObject myObj = (MyObject) getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MyObject.class.getCanonicalName());

            if(myObj == null){
                ch_check = null;
            } else{
                ch_check = myObj.choise;
            }
        }

        if(ch_check != null){

            try {
                createListsList(ch_check);
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            prepareListData();

            expListView.setChoiceMode(AbsListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
            listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, pages, listDataChild);
            expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);

            expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, long id) {

                    return false;
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), pages.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {

                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),pages.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),pages.get(groupPosition) + " : " + listDataChild.get(pages.get(groupPosition)).get( childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.lblListChildCheckbox);
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                    checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                            checkBox.setChecked(isChecked);
                        }
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }

    }
```

Добавляю вид того, что из этого вышло. Но состояние чекбоксы детей не зависят от родителей, к тому же состояние самих чекбоксов после сворачивания-разворачивания меняется хаотично внутри ветки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: такого виджета среди системных нет, а написать самому - задача не для средних умов. Предлагаю не тратить время (его потребуется много), а использовать другой паттерн, более подходящий для мобильного устройства, например, вложенные одноранговые списки (ListView). В первом основные разделы, при нажатии на один из разделов, открывается второй список с подразделами и тд. В каждом таком списке есть чекбоксы для отметки разделов/подразделов

Comment: Подобное уже реализовано, но под поставленные задачи оно не подходит, необходим именно подобный список, как я описал выше (иначе просто особого смысла нет реализовывать подобное). Может кто занимался подобным или натыкался на пример, пока интересует лишь зависимость состояния чекбоксов детей, от состояния родителя

Comment: Вроде не совсем то, но думаю что можно попробовать доделать под себя https://android-arsenal.com/details/3/2050

Comment: Добавил скрин того, что уже имеется на данный момент.